# Pyspark TextParsingException while loading a file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am loading a csv file having 1 million records using pyspark, but getting the error. TextParsingException: Length of parsed input (1000001) exceeds the maximum number of characters defined in your parser settings (1000000)

I checked if any of my record in the file has data greater than 1000000 characters, but none of the record is like that. maximum record length in my file is 850.

Please help....

```
CODE SNIPPET:
        input_df =  spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter","\001").option("quote",u"\u0000").load(INPUT_PATH)
        input_df.write.mode('overwrite').format('orc').save(TARGET_LOC)

    SAMPLE DATA

        A    B     C
        --   --    --
        a   xyz"a  123
        b   pqr    456
        c   ABC"z  789
```

Comment: Show your code and data sample.

Comment: Which version of spark? There used to be an issue (github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/295) about that in earlier than 2.0 versions. As for the maximum record length, if you have nested quotes or special characters, according to the issuem spark tried to add as many rows and then it crashed. –

Comment: spark version is 2.0.2.  Seems my data has nested quotes, is there any way to handle it

Comment: Could you please add the code so that we can see what else you can do to handle it?

Comment: @mkaran - edited my question

Comment: Your DF says that delimiter is `\001` whereas your sample data's delimiter appears to be `\t`.  Which one is the correct delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the parser setting limiting the number of character per columns, using

```
option("maxCharsPerColumn", "-1")
```

so this now should work as:

```
spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter","\001").option("quote",u"\u0000").option("maxCharsPerColumn", "-1").load(INPUT_PATH)
```

else you can also try changing your parser:

```
.option("parserLib", "commons")
```