# com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: Length of parsed input (1000001) exceeds the maximum number of character

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark script but getting the above error. I used option("maxCharsPerCol","1100000") but not able to fix the issue.

Can you please help me how to resolve this issue?
Pyspark version - 2.0.0

I am using below code while reading and writing the file:

reading:

```
df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\001').option("maxCharsPerCol","1000001L").options(header='true',inferSchema='false').load(row['Source File Name Lnd'])
```

writing:

```
df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').save(output_path, sep='\001',header='True',nullValue=None)
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 15, localhost): com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: Length of parsed input (1000001) exceeds the maximum number of characters defined in your parser settings (1000000). 
Identified line separator characters in the parsed content. This may be the cause of the error. The line separator in your parser settings is set to '\n'. Parsed content:
```

Comment: have you tried the solution from the similar stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108541/pyspark-textparsingexception-while-loading-a-file

Comment: @pastaleg i have tried with all the option like - option("maxCharsPerCol","-1") & option("maxCharsPerCol","1000001L") & option("maxCharsPerCol","110000") & option("parserLib", "commons") .....but getting the same error.

Comment: @pastaleg .. Have you any other solution sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using below option:

In Some File I am using `quote=''`

```
df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\001').options(header='true', quote='',inferSchema='false').load(row['Source File Name Lnd'])
```

In some files I am using `escape=''`

```
df_read_file = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\001').options(header='true', escape='',inferSchema='false').load(row['Source File Name Lnd'])
```

Run with this option I am able to solve my problem.